Why do Apps and Features and ODBC administrator show different versions for the same driver?
I am running Windows 10.
Today I uninstalled the 64-bit ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server and reinstalled it, to ensure I had the latest version. I downloaded the driver from the usual Microsoft site.
When I look at the version in Apps and Features, it reports the version as 18.4.1.1, and the date as today's date (21 Oct 2024), as I would expect.
However, the ODBC Data Source Administrator (64-bit) reports (for ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server) a version of 2018.184.01.01 and a date of 11 Jul 2024, which I believe is unchanged from the previous installation (not sure).
Rebooting the PC made no difference.
Can anyone explain what is going on here?
EDIT:
My machine is locked down, so I had to get IT to install the driver as this required admin privileges. Here are screenshots of the issue:
What Apps and Features reports:

What ODBC Administrator reports:


Can you provide a screenshot?

When you installed the new ODBC drivers, was that as user or admin?

@Ramhound screenshots added

@DrMoishe Pippik it was as admin.

You’ll need your system administrator to troubleshoot the reason the correct version of 18 isn’t showing up. ODBC 17 is showing up despite not apparently being installed, my only theory, is that it’s connected to the OLE DB driver. What originally prompted you to reinstall the driver? Was it due to one of the bug fixes?

The reason for re-installation was that I wanted to be sure I had the latest extant version. A colleague with an earlier version had been encountering non-optimal behaviour (like retrieving the rows of a big SELECT one at a time from the data source!) and I wanted to rule out the driver as a possible contributor to the problem.

@Ramhound The Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server can be installed side by side with Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server.

@marktwo - I am familiar with the product. The only driver that apparently installed is ODBC 18 according to your screenshot. Do you by chance have VS installed, and did you install the ODBC through VS installer, might explain the version mismatch

Yes I do have Visual Studio 2019 installed actually, though don't use it much. It is possible that the driver got installed as part of the VS data access bundle.
